# Searching for dict in list in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm very new, and I'm working on a project that right now involves writing a function that will search for a dictionary contained in a list which is itself the value of one of two key/value pairs in another dictionary. The goal is to search for a movie by title, and then remove that movie's dict from that list and put it in a different list. Right now I've got

```
def watch_movie(user_data, title):

    if title in user_data:
        user_data["watchlist"].remove(title)
        user_data["watched"].append(title)
        return user_data

    else:
        return user_data
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please provide a sample list.

Comment: Please show example

Comment: Right, sorry, yes. I'm running  a test provided by a course, so this is the data it's inputting

`janes_data = {"watchlist": [{"title": "Title A", "genre": "Fantasy", "rating": 4.8}], "watched": []} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `for` loop to compare the `title` of each dict to the input:

```
def watch_movie(user_data, title):
    for d in user_data['watchlist']:
        if d['title'] == title:
            user_data["watchlist"].remove(d)
            user_data["watched"].append(d)
        break # assuming no two movies share the same title
    return user_data

user_data = {"watchlist": [{"title": "Title A", "genre": "Fantasy", "rating": 4.8}], "watched": []}
user_data = watch_movie(user_data, 'Title A')
print(user_data) # {'watchlist': [], 'watched': [{'title': 'Title A', 'genre': 'Fantasy', 'rating': 4.8}]}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but the test is returning a failure. I think maybe I'm not realizing I have to find a way to move the whole movie dict instead of just the title?

Comment: Oh that is data structure you have! I'll update the answer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, what a huge help.